# Find an angle between two integral lines at a given point.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, I am given two differential equtions: $x'=x-t^2$ and $x'=2x+t^2$, and the point $M=(1,-2)$. I need to find an angle between the integral lines of these differential equations. What is the general way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Let the angle be $\theta$. Then,

$$\tan\theta = \tan(\theta_2-\theta_1) 
= \frac{\tan\theta_2-\tan\theta_1}{1+\tan\theta_2\tan\theta_1}
=\frac{x_2'-x_1'}{1+x_2'x_1'}
=\frac{(2x+t^2)-(x-t^2)}{1+(2x+t^2)(x-t^2)}$$

Now, substitute $t=1$ and $x=-2$.